# NodeJS + Socket.IO through multiple pages

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Ok, so I'm struggling with it for all the morning, and cannot find solution ( or maybe I'm just missing something ).

```
TL;DR
```

Question:1 - how long persist socket in Socket.IO? When it fire 'disconnect' event? When I close a tab, or just change a route(e.g from /category to /recipe)?

Question:2 - Do you have some tuts, articles, or suggestions, how this app ( that use socket.io + express on multiple pages ) should look like?

```
More info
```

I'd like to create Admin Panel in Express, with routes:

`/category
/recipe
/ingredients`

Lets now say that we have 2 admins adding together some content. I want them to see, what each of them have just added, without refreshing site. And here comes the Socket.IO

By now I thought it can be done this way:

1. socket authentication ( `socket.sessionID = userCookies['sid']` ) ---> (`sid` is created by express.session middleware), now I know if the socket belongs to the user
2. In separate file registry all events (e.g. `handleCategoryCreate` )
3. In routes join the room (e.g. in `/category` route, before render our view, call `socket.join('/category')` and `socket.leave(previousRoom)` )
4. When admin click the ADD button, it fires the event, `socket.emit('new category has been added')` for all users in current room (e.g. `/category`)

I don't like my approach, becouse it seems to be very messy + i've to create some GLOBAL hash, that would keep `{sid => socket}` (for easy access to sockets in routes), and not sure how to do it nice way.

I'd appreciate any help, because i'm really lost

EDIT:
if this will be helpful i put my code on git: https://github.com/matDobek/eatDat , files worth seeing:

1. `lib/socketapp`
2. `app.js`

Comment: the website content looks very static, i mean you don't expect it to change very ofter, using socket.io looks too much .. either way if its just admin stuff, try to create a room and emit events to everybody who is in that room.

Comment: it's just website for learning purpose. And I'd like to find some good solution tying socket.io and express together, and use it as skeleton on other sites :)